# Reconciling two different concepts of conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory

So in class I learned that the conditional probability $Z = P[X \in A | Y] = E[1_{X \in A} | Y]$ is defined as the random variable $Z$ where $Z$ is $Y$-measurable and $E[1_B 1_{X \in A}] = E[1_B Z]$ for all $B \in \sigma(Y)$.  However, in earlier probability classes I learned that
$$
Z = \frac{\int_A f(x, Y) dx}{\int_\mathbb{R} f(x, Y) dx}
$$
is there a way to reconcile this difference?

Comment: No, since the latter $Z$ is a constant and the first $Z$ is a random variable. However, the latter expression is one way to define $P[X\in A\mid Y=y]$ _when_ $(X,Y)$ admits a joint density. If we let $\varphi(y)=P[X\in A\mid Y=y]$, then you can simply check that $\varphi(Y)$ is in fact $P[X\in A\mid Y]$.

Comment: Sorry, I had some improper notation.  Does this make sense now?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. So what is holding you back from showing that the variable $Z=\int_A f(x,Y)\mathrm dx/\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,Y)\mathrm dx$ satisfies the requirements for being the conditional expectation $\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_{X\in A}\mid Y]$?

Comment: What @Stefan said. The only possibly missing piece I can see to deduce a full proof is that every $B$ in $\sigma(Y)$ is $B=[Y\in C]$ for some measurable $C$.

Comment: I'm confused as to how to show that $E[1_B 1_{X \in A}] = P[X^{-1}(A) \cap B] = E[1_B Z]$ for all $B \in \sigma(Y)$.

Comment: I have something like $\int_B \frac{\int_A f(x, y) dx}{\int_\mathbb{R} f(x, y) dx} g(y) dy$ but I'm not sure what $g(y)$ would be

Comment: Got anything from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi(y)=\int_A f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx / \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx$ and let us show that $\varphi(Y)$ is indeed the conditional expectation $\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_A(X)\mid Y]$. It is clear that $\varphi(Y)$ is measurable so we only need to check that ${\rm E}[\mathbf{1}_B\varphi(Y)]=\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_B\mathbf{1}_A(X)]$ for all $B\in\sigma(Y)$.

If $B\in\sigma(Y)$, then $B=Y^{-1}(C)$ for some Borel set $C$, and hence
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_B\varphi(Y)]&=\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_C(Y)\varphi(Y)]=\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbf{1}_C(y)\varphi(y)f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R}\mathbf{1}_C(y)\mathbf{1}_A(x)f(x,y)\,\mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy=P(X^{-1}(A)\cap B).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This may be stupid but it's not even obvious to me that $\psi(Y)$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(Y)$.

Comment: Well, $\sigma(\psi(Y))\subseteq\sigma(Y)$ for _any_ measurable transformation $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. This should be pretty straightforward to show.

Comment: $[\psi(Y)\in B]=[Y\in C]$ with $C=\psi^{-1}(B)$.